# How to use global git exclude in VSCode with DevContainers

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I would like to always ignore certain files, so I created a .gitignore-global file in my home folder, which is respected in VSCode - *except* when I am developing in a devcontainer.

Is there a simple way to use the same .gitignore-global file, rather than having to create one (or add some configuration directive) for every devcontainer?

Update - I have found the `search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles` setting in VSCode and enabled it for User and Remote Dev Container, but it isn't being used.

Comment: Do you normally deploy your dotfiles to your devcontainer?

Comment: When you say "your dotfiles" what do you mean? All the files and folders starting with a . in the user profile folder on the host machine?

Answer (score 1):

Often, one has a repository with personal dotfiles or other configuration (sometimes including scripts) that one installs to new dev environments (laptops, VMs, containers, etc.).  For example, I use Vim or Neovim and zsh, and I have my configurations for those in [my dotfiles repository](https://github.com/bk2204/dotfiles).  When I set up a new system or dev environment, I always clone my dotfiles repository and run the install script to configure the environment appropriately.  That way, my environment is consistent and always as I want it to be.

The default location for the global (user-specific) gitignore is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`, or, if `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set, `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`.  Thus, if you install the file into that location as part of your dotfiles repository as part of your container setup, then it will be available and used by default.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look in your repository but could not figure out which is the install script - could you give me a pointer?

Comment: It's the makefile, with the `rules.mk` in each directory being included.

Comment: Thanks - I thought it might be, but wanted to check as I am not familiar with makefiles.  I'll take a closer look and figure it out.

Comment: I just asked a similar question (you might consider it the same, or having the same answer) so just a heads up - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77191702/246433